# Question about proof of Lemma 2.41 - Sipser book

Tags: pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

[image]

Doesn't the modification described in paragraph three potentially introduce non-determinism? For example, say neither *a*, *b*, *x*, nor *y* is the empty string (denoted *e*). If in the original machine *P* we have:

```
f(q, e, x) != null
f(q, a, y) != null
f(q, b, y) != null
```

wouldn't the modification give us:

```
f(q, e, $) != null
f(q, a, $) != null
f(q, b, $) != null
```

To elaborate, say the original machine got stuck in an accept state Q that sometimes reads and always pops (so the decision to read depends on the stack) with one symbol left to be read. The modified machine both does and doesn't read this last symbol before going to the next state. I would say it should reject, since states like Q would have to first pop and then read.

Comment: At first glance it seems you are right. Note the book has quite some errata for that page.Have a look, whether one of those solves your problem. See: http://math.mit.edu/~sipser/itoc-errs3.1.html